# how to fix scroll down issue in selenium its tiktok bot in chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

I want help from someone my code is not working I'm trying to make a bot that follows and scrolls on TikTok and I don't know what I'm doing wrong(code executes in the first video then stops by it self) I'm new to coding and I tried my best with it nothing worked with me I hope u guys can help I put the whole code down there.

---

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver import Keys, ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import os
from random import randint
from time import sleep

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "localhost:9222")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://www.tiktok.com/foryou')
driver.maximize_window()
```

###problem start from here where i make the bot scroll and it just follow and scroll the first video then scroll back up and stop moving

```
n = 10
for n in range(100):
time.sleep(2)

#follow click code using xpath
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="main-content-homepage_hot"]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]').click()
time.sleep(2)

#scroll down code 
webdriver.ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()
```

Comment: Usually you'll need to be accurate when using `By.XPATH` because you don't know how the page changes the elements and using static indexes for divs is a very poor identification method. Try to detect the element based on either `text`, `id` or other attributes